# Can't install apps from Test flight. There was an error with this request

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

After "Reset All Settings" on an iPhone 5 with iOS 8.3, I can't install betas via TestFlight.

[image]

Comment: others are also experiencing the same issue. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35404379/ios-test-flight-error-testflight-could-not-install-app-there-was-an-error-wit#comment58510594_35404379

Comment: Should be a certificate issue. You can try  to re-invite tester one more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@azimov the problem is coming from OS 8.3, we all have the same issue only with devices on OS 8.3. 
I personally tried to re-invite, change the apple account, even reset my phone...

Comment: Thanks! Updated to iOS 9.2.1 and problem was solved. Looks like there's no solution for iOS 8.3, just update.

Answer (score -2):

I have this issue as well. On the same hardware, iOS 9 users are fine, 8.3 users cannot install.

I did not have this issue on Feb 1.

Comment: Same problem on my device.