# Error testing app on iOS 8.3: Testflight could not install app. There was an error with this request

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I updated my Xcode to 7.2. I sent an app build to testers and one tester had the following error:

```
Testflight could not install app. There was an error with this request
```

His device is an iPad 2 running iOS 8.3. Deleting the user and reinstalling the app has no effect.

What is causing this and how can we prevent Testflight installs from failing with this error?

Comment: only one user have the problem or all users ?

Comment: Can you check your provisioning profiles to see they're still valid and assigned correctly?

Comment: @Signare Only one user. He has two devices: iPhone 6S OS 9.x and iPad 2 OS 8.3. And the problem is only on iPad.

Comment: Weird, I have this error on another device, and it just started happening with two apps, after one was able to successfully download in the past.

Comment: This happened today for me to.  One tester out of 7 can't install the app.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's iOS 8.3. I have the same issue on my iPhone 6 with iOS 8.3 and I see others have the exact same issue with this version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397965/cant-install-apps-from-test-flight-there-was-an-error-with-this-request

Comment: I too am encountering this error. Specifically on iOS 8.3 all of our other users with iOS 9 on the same hardware do not have the issue.